# Why my website is showing mobile usability error in google search console? (Only the wp-content pages are showing this error)

Tags: wordpress, plugins, robots.txt, google-search-console

My website is showing mobile usability errors in the google search console for the past 7-8 days. It is showing 2 types of errors. Like

1. Text too small to read
2. Clickable elements too close together

**16 of my pages are affected. But the matter of concern is that the affected pages are not my post or pages, rather they are wp-content pages, which are not for the visitors. These pages should never be shown by the visitors because they are folders stored in my root directory. But unwantedly google is showing a mobile usability error on these pages.**

Example of the page URLs

```
https://mywebsite.com/wp-content/plugins/ultimate-post/assets/img/admin/?SA

https://mywebsite.com/wp-content/plugins/ultimate-post/assets/img/admin/?SD

https://mywebsite.com/wp-content/plugins/ultimate-post/assets/img/addons/

https://mywebsite.com/wp-content/plugins/ultimate-post/assets/img/layouts/toc/?MA

https://mywebsite.com/wp-content/plugins/wpforms-lite/assets/images/?SA
```

like this.

Will this issue negatively hamper my site? Because all visitors of my site are organic and most of them are mobile users.

How should I fix this issue? Please guide me.